# Duplicate materials

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I've got a question: How can I connect the .000 and .001 materials to one ? Because I want to use separate by Materials on my object, but it separates the duplicate materials too. (.000 and .001)

Example pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are duplicated materials which you'd like to get rid of *unused* ones, i.e. unused by any other object in scene ? This can be checked by number *0* next to the material name in the dropdown list of materials.

Answer (score 2):

This addon fixed the datablock issue:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Datablock_Tools

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can either:

In the Materials Pane select the materials you don't want to use and then click the button with the “-“ symbol on it to remove the materials from your object. **Note** that the material will still be available to you in the material drop down menu.

[image]

Or

Select your object and “Tab” into Edit Mode then select the Face(s) that you want to add a color then in the Materials Pane select a material and the press the “Assign” button. **Note** that this option is only available in Edit Mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have 90 meshes in my real model and it would be very long time to do this with the all of the meshes.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file here? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry, The model isn't public.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding one of the materials to both cubes. This should leave the other material unused (a *0* should appear next to its name in the materials menu). Also make sure the unused material doesn't have the *F* next to its name selected. The *F*, *F*orces it to hang around even when it shouldn't.

Once you can see the *0* next to it in the list, save your file, close out of Blender, and reopen your file again. Your *0*-ed material should have disappeared during the refresh.

Comment: What is F Forces ?

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian Sorry for being unclear. I meant the F, Forces blah de blah to happen. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: +1 for this solution , you can speed up the process of adding fake users by shift [selecting them in the outliner](http://i.stack.imgur.com/stA3T.png) , and clicking purge to get rid of the unwanted materials.

Comment: I just want to remove the .number from my materials, nothing special.

Comment: Then click either once or twice on the name to edit it. Once again, please consider accepting my answer.